# Вывод определенного столбца (sql)

Tags: python, sqlite

Всем привет. делаю сейчас телеграм бота, хочу внедрить фичу, теперь такой вопрос:
допустим у меня в sqlite (python) таблице есть два столбца, "username" и "id". мне к примеру нужно по id(который я введу вручную) из базы вытащить username который относится к id, как это сделать?)

Comment: Для этого нужно отредактировать свой вопрос так, чтобы в нем были видны ваши попытки решить эту проблему. чем больше конкретики, тем лучше.

Answer (score 0):

```
id = 1
q='SELECT username FROM users WHERE id =? '
cursor.execute(q, (id,) )
username = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```